# I always get this error message when I want to add a reference to the Farseer project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I want to add a reference to the Farseer Physics MonoGame project, but it is impossible to add a reference because I always get this error message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone
>
> Unable to add the specified project reference. The reference must be a Windows Phone project that targets the current or earlier version of the Windows Phone OS.

What is wrong? What should I change? What does this message mean?

You can see the error message in this picture:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Do you have the right library? Where did you obtain it from? Sounds like it's not compatible with Windows Phone.

Comment: I downloaded it from the official site: http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/releases/view/110074  There is also a Farseer Windows Phone project in the download package, and that one can be referenced. But I thought that I should use the Farseer Monogame project, because I use Monogame to make a Windows Phone game. I don't know what the difference between the Farseer Windows Phone project and the Farseer Monogame project is.

Comment: Those won't mix -- you'll need to use the Windows Phone assemblies unless the Monogame project uses a portable class library (which it apparently does not or you wouldn't have received that error).

Comment: I added a reference to the Farseer Windows Phone project. But when I debug, I get the following error message: Metadata file 'C:\Users\John\Documents\Farseer Physics Engine 3.5 Samples\Farseer Physics Engine 3.5 Samples\Farseer Physics Engine 3.5\bin\Windows Phone\Debug\FarseerPhysics WP7.dll' could not be found   What is wrong?